# Как правильно указать время жизни ссылки в реализации трэйта

Tags: rust, время-жизни

Как реализовать `TraitFoo` для структуры `Foo`?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'f>{
    os: Option<&'f str>
}

impl<'f> Foo<'f> {
    fn new(x:&'f str) -> Foo<'f>{
        Foo{
            os:Some(x)
        }       
    }
}

trait TraitFoo {
    fn foo(x:&str) -> Self;
}

impl<'f> TraitFoo for Foo<'f>{
    fn foo(x:&str) -> Foo<'f> {
        Foo{
            os:Some(x)
        }
    }
}




fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Foo::new("one"));
    println!("{:?}", Foo::foo("two"));
}
```

Этот код компилится с ошибкой:

```
 G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:21:12: 21:13 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:21          os:Some(x)
                                                        ^
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:19:2: 23:3 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn foo(x: &'f str) -> Foo<'f>
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:19  fn foo(x:&str) -> Foo<'f> {
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:20      Foo{
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:21          os:Some(x)
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:22      }
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:23  }
```

Если добавить `'f` в функции `foo()` то получим другую ошибку:

```
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:19:2: 23:3 error: method `foo` has an incompatible type for trait: expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime [E0053]
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:19  fn foo(x:&'f str) -> Foo<'f> {
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:20      Foo{
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:21          os:Some(x)
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:22      }
G:\Work\Rust\test01\src\lf_trait.rs:23  }
```

Перепробовал еще кучу вариантов. Объясните как это правильно сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот ответ с английского форума от llogiq:

Нужно указать время жизни в определении трэйта

```
trait TraitFoo<'a> {
    fn foo(x: &'a str) -> Self;
}

impl<'a> TraitFoo<'a> for Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(x:&'a str) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo{
            os:Some(x)
        }
    }
}
```